# JSON Header Array in Java

Tags: java, json, curl, httprequest

I need to POST data in getting IOT results:

Am getting the Error as follows:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation
>   problems:     JSONObject cannot be resolved to a type     JSONObject cannot
>   be resolved to a type
>     at IOT.httpPostWithBody.sendJSONData(httpPostWithBody.java:40)  at
>   IOT.httpPostWithBody.main(httpPostWithBody.java:27)

My JAVA Program As Follows:

```
package IOT;

//package com.test.Second;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.entity.StringEntity;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicHeader;
import org.apache.http.protocol.HTTP;
import org.json.JSONObject;


public class httpPostWithBody {

public static void main(String args[]) {
    String Message = "6f2159f998";

    try {
        new httpPostWithBody().sendJSONData(Message);
    } catch (Exception E) {
System.out.println("Exception Occured. " + E.getMessage());
    }
    }

public String sendJSONData(String message) throws Exception {

    //creating map object to create JSON object from it
Map< String, Object >jsonValues = new HashMap< String, Object >();
jsonValues.put("thing_key",message);
jsonValues.put("from", "2016/08/29 16:55:00");
jsonValues.put("to", "2016/08/29 17:05:00");
jsonValues.put("time_zone", "Asia/Calcutta");
jsonValues.put("per", "200");
jsonValues.put("metrics", "1st data");

JSONObject json = new JSONObject(jsonValues);


String url = "https://api.datonis.io/api/v3/datonis_query/thing_data";
DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost post = new HttpPost(url);
post.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
post.setHeader("X-Auth-Token", "TtJd3Qb9eq5xqPfK2zabXg");
//setting json object to post request.
StringEntity entity = new StringEntity(json.toString(), "UTF8");
entity.setContentType(new BasicHeader(HTTP.CONTENT_TYPE, "application/json"));
post.setEntity(entity);
//this is your response:
HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);
System.out.println("Response: " + response.getStatusLine());
    return response.getStatusLine().toString();
}
}
```

Comment: Did you add the JSON library to the build path?

Comment: Try cleaning your project. If you are using Eclipse ide, Go to Project > Clean.

Comment: After Clean am getting this.Error: Could not find or load main class IOT.httpPostWithBody

Comment: How did you run, through Eclipse? And Did your compilation error got fixed?

Comment: No. Am getting a new error. The error as follows: Error: Could not find or load main class IOT.httpPostWithBody

First time am trying this clean. Don't know what to do next.

Comment: Update question with a screen shot of your project in Eclipse with project structure in the screen shot. You will get this error when you run your class.

Comment: There is no error/warning in the program. anyhow, I am in a different trouble now.  with the new error as given you in the last post. Don't know how to come out of that.

Comment: Is the error coming when you run `httpPostWithBody` class through Eclipse or through command prompt.

Comment: Can you try this code in your eclipse / command and revert back to me?

Answer (score 0):

In the question URL had a error the same has been resolved now.

```
package IOT;

import java.util.HashMap;  
import java.util.Map;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.entity.StringEntity;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicHeader;
import org.apache.http.protocol.HTTP;
import org.json.JSONObject;


public class HttpPostWithBody {

public static void main(String args[]) {
    String Message = "62159f998";

    try {
        new HttpPostWithBody().sendJSONData(Message);
    } catch (Exception E) {
System.out.println("Exception Occured. " + E.getMessage());
    }
    }

public String sendJSONData(String message) throws Exception {

    //creating map object to create JSON object from it
Map< String, Object >jsonValues = new HashMap< String, Object >();
jsonValues.put("sensor_key",message);
jsonValues.put("from", "2016/08/29 16:55:00");
jsonValues.put("to", "2016/08/29 17:05:00");
jsonValues.put("time_zone", "Mumbai");
jsonValues.put("per", "50");
jsonValues.put("metrics", "1st data");

JSONObject json = new JSONObject(jsonValues);


String url = "https://api.datonis.io/api/v2/datonis_query/thing_event_raw_data";

DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost post = new HttpPost(url);
post.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
post.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
post.setHeader("X-Auth-Token", "9v8IjBku0a9y-D7SpLq6ZA");

//setting json object to post request.
StringEntity entity = new StringEntity(json.toString(), "UTF8");
entity.setContentType(new BasicHeader(HTTP.CONTENT_TYPE, "application/json"));

post.setEntity(entity);
//this is your response:
HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);
System.out.println("Response: " + response.getStatusLine());
return response.getStatusLine().toString();
} 
}
```